# Use WebRTC camera in AR-session Android

Tags: android, arcore, webrtc-android

I'm trying to replace the frames from the device camera (which is normaly used in an AR session) with frames from a streamed camera via webrtc. To render the  webrtc stream I'm using `webrtc.SurfaceViewRenderer` and to render the AR session I'm using `opengl.GLSurfaceView`in `activity_main.xml` and this two viewers works as they are supposed to do separately but now I want to combine them. The problem is that I dont know how to extract the frames from the webrtc stream. The closets function I have found is `Bitmap bmp = surfaceViewRenderer.getDrawingCache();` to capture the pixels but it always return null.

If I can get the pixles from the surfaceViewRenderer my idea is then to bind it to a texture and then render this texture as a background in the AR-scene

The code I have been following can be found at https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/blob/master/samples/hello_ar_java/app/src/main/java/com/google/ar/core/examples/java/helloar/HelloArActivity.java

This is the code where the AR scene is rendered using the device camera:

```
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl10) {

    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    try {
            session.setCameraTextureName(backgroundRenderer.getTextureId());

            //replace this frame with the frames that is rendered in webrtc's SurfaceViewRenderer
            Frame frame = session.update();
            Camera camera = frame.getCamera();

            backgroundRenderer.draw(frame);
    .
    .
    .
```

And this is how my `activity_main.xml` looks like. In the end I will remove the SurfaceViewRenderer section

```
<LinearLayout
    <org.webrtc.SurfaceViewRenderer
     android:id="@+id/local_gl_surface_view"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="248dp"
     android:layout_gravity="bottom|end" />

    <android.opengl.GLSurfaceView
     android:id="@+id/surfaceview"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="195dp"
     android:layout_gravity="top" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Have you found a solution yet?

Comment: Unfortunately not. It's been a while since I worked on this project.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question but if anyone requires the answer, here it is.

So after brainstorming for days and after a lot of RnD, I've found a workaround.
You don't need anything extra to add.
So the story here is to use ArCore and WebRtc At the same time and sharing what you see in your ArCore session to the WebRtc so that the remote user sees them. Correct?

Well, the trick is to give your camera to ArCore and instead of sharing the Camera with webrtc, create a screen share Video Capturer. Its pretty simple and WebRtc already supports it natively. (Let me know if you need the source code too).

Open your ArCore activity in the full screen by setting all those flags to your window. And start your ArCore Session as normal, after that initialise your webrtc call and provide the screen sharing logic instead of the video source and Voila! ArCore + WebRTC.

I implemented this with no issues and the latency is good too. ~100ms

**Edit**

I think sharing screen isn't a good idea (The remote user will be able to see all the sensitive data such as notifications and etc.).
Rather what I did is

> extend the ViewCapturer class of WebRTC.

> use PixelCopy class to create bitmaps.

and feed it with the **SurfaceView** in which your ArCore session is being played and then converting it to bitmaps and those bitmaps to frames and then sending it to the WebRTC's **onFrameCapruted** function.

This way you can just share your SurfaceView instead of sharing the complete screen and also you don't need any extra permission such as screen recording and this looks way much better like an actual realtime video sharing.

**Edited 2 (Final Solution)**

Step 1:

Create a custom video capturer that'll extend VideoCapturer of webrtc

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.opengl.GLES20;
import android.opengl.GLUtils;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.HandlerThread;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.PixelCopy;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;

import com.jaswant.webRTCIsAwesome.ArSessionActivity;

import org.webrtc.CapturerObserver;
import org.webrtc.JavaI420Buffer;
import org.webrtc.SurfaceTextureHelper;
import org.webrtc.TextureBufferImpl;
import org.webrtc.VideoCapturer;
import org.webrtc.VideoFrame;
import org.webrtc.VideoSink;
import org.webrtc.YuvConverter;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
public class CustomVideoCapturer implements VideoCapturer, VideoSink {

private static int VIEW_CAPTURER_FRAMERATE_MS = 10;
private int width;
private int height;
private SurfaceView view;
private Context context;
private CapturerObserver capturerObserver;
private SurfaceTextureHelper surfaceTextureHelper;
private boolean isDisposed;
private Bitmap viewBitmap;
private Handler handlerPixelCopy = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
private Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
private AtomicBoolean started = new AtomicBoolean(false);
private long numCapturedFrames;
private YuvConverter yuvConverter = new YuvConverter();
private TextureBufferImpl buffer;
private long start = System.nanoTime();
private final Runnable viewCapturer = new Runnable() {
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Override
    public void run() {
        boolean dropFrame = view.getWidth() == 0 || view.getHeight() == 0;

        // Only capture the view if the dimensions have been established
        if (!dropFrame) {
            // Draw view into bitmap backed canvas
            final Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            final HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread(ArSessionActivity.class.getSimpleName());
            handlerThread.start();
            try {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                    PixelCopy.request(view, bitmap, copyResult -> {
                        if (copyResult == PixelCopy.SUCCESS) {
                            viewBitmap = getResizedBitmap(bitmap, 500);
                            if (viewBitmap != null) {
                                Log.d("BITMAP--->", viewBitmap.toString());
                                sendToServer(viewBitmap, yuvConverter, start);
                            }
                        } else {
                            Log.e("Pixel_copy-->", "Couldn't create bitmap of the SurfaceView");
                        }
                        handlerThread.quitSafely();
                    }, new Handler(handlerThread.getLooper()));
                } else {
                    Log.i("Pixel_copy-->", "Saving an image of a SurfaceView is only supported from API 24");
                }
            } catch (Exception ignored) {
            }
        }
    }
};
private Thread captureThread;

public CustomVideoCapturer(SurfaceView view, int framePerSecond) {
    if (framePerSecond <= 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("framePersecond must be greater than 0");
    this.view = view;
    float tmp = (1f / framePerSecond) * 1000;
    VIEW_CAPTURER_FRAMERATE_MS = Math.round(tmp);
}

private static void bitmapToI420(Bitmap src, JavaI420Buffer dest) {
    int width = src.getWidth();
    int height = src.getHeight();
    if (width != dest.getWidth() || height != dest.getHeight())
        return;
    int strideY = dest.getStrideY();
    int strideU = dest.getStrideU();
    int strideV = dest.getStrideV();
    ByteBuffer dataY = dest.getDataY();
    ByteBuffer dataU = dest.getDataU();
    ByteBuffer dataV = dest.getDataV();
    for (int line = 0; line < height; line++) {
        if (line % 2 == 0) {
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x += 2) {
                int px = src.getPixel(x, line);
                byte r = (byte) ((px >> 16) & 0xff);
                byte g = (byte) ((px >> 8) & 0xff);
                byte b = (byte) (px & 0xff);
                dataY.put(line * strideY + x, (byte) (((66 * r + 129 * g + 25 * b) >> 8) + 16));
                dataU.put(line / 2 * strideU + x / 2, (byte) (((-38 * r + -74 * g + 112 * b) >> 8) + 128));
                dataV.put(line / 2 * strideV + x / 2, (byte) (((112 * r + -94 * g + -18 * b) >> 8) + 128));
                px = src.getPixel(x + 1, line);
                r = (byte) ((px >> 16) & 0xff);
                g = (byte) ((px >> 8) & 0xff);
                b = (byte) (px & 0xff);
                dataY.put(line * strideY + x, (byte) (((66 * r + 129 * g + 25 * b) >> 8) + 16));
            }
        } else {
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x += 1) {
                int px = src.getPixel(x, line);
                byte r = (byte) ((px >> 16) & 0xff);
                byte g = (byte) ((px >> 8) & 0xff);
                byte b = (byte) (px & 0xff);
                dataY.put(line * strideY + x, (byte) (((66 * r + 129 * g + 25 * b) >> 8) + 16));
            }
        }
    }
}

public static Bitmap createFlippedBitmap(Bitmap source, boolean xFlip, boolean yFlip) {
    try {
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postScale(xFlip ? -1 : 1, yFlip ? -1 : 1, source.getWidth() / 2f, source.getHeight() / 2f);
        return Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(), matrix, true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}

private void checkNotDisposed() {
    if (this.isDisposed) {
        throw new RuntimeException("capturer is disposed.");
    }
}

@Override
public synchronized void initialize(SurfaceTextureHelper surfaceTextureHelper, Context context, CapturerObserver capturerObserver) {
    this.checkNotDisposed();
    if (capturerObserver == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("capturerObserver not set.");
    } else {
        this.context = context;
        this.capturerObserver = capturerObserver;
        if (surfaceTextureHelper == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("surfaceTextureHelper not set.");
        } else {
            this.surfaceTextureHelper = surfaceTextureHelper;
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void startCapture(int width, int height, int fps) {
    this.checkNotDisposed();
    this.started.set(true);
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.capturerObserver.onCapturerStarted(true);
    this.surfaceTextureHelper.startListening(this);
    handler.postDelayed(viewCapturer, VIEW_CAPTURER_FRAMERATE_MS);


    /*try {
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread(CustomVideoCapturer.class.getSimpleName());
        capturerObserver.onCapturerStarted(true);
        int[] textures = new int[1];
        GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);
        YuvConverter yuvConverter = new YuvConverter();
        TextureBufferImpl buffer = new TextureBufferImpl(width, height, VideoFrame.TextureBuffer.Type.RGB, textures[0], new Matrix(), surfaceTextureHelper.getHandler(), yuvConverter, null);
     //   handlerThread.start();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            new Thread(() -> {
                while (true) {
                    PixelCopy.request(view, bitmap, copyResult -> {
                        if (copyResult == PixelCopy.SUCCESS) {
                            viewBitmap = getResizedBitmap(bitmap, 500);
                            long start = System.nanoTime();
                            Log.d("BITMAP--->", viewBitmap.toString());
                            sendToServer(viewBitmap, yuvConverter, buffer, start);
                        } else {
                            Log.e("Pixel_copy-->", "Couldn't create bitmap of the SurfaceView");
                        }
                        handlerThread.quitSafely();
                    }, new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()));
                }
            }).start();
        }
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
    }*/
}

private void sendToServer(Bitmap bitmap, YuvConverter yuvConverter, long start) {
    try {
        int[] textures = new int[1];
        GLES20.glGenTextures(0, textures, 0);
        buffer = new TextureBufferImpl(width, height, VideoFrame.TextureBuffer.Type.RGB, textures[0], new Matrix(), surfaceTextureHelper.getHandler(), yuvConverter, null);
        Bitmap flippedBitmap = createFlippedBitmap(bitmap, true, false);
        surfaceTextureHelper.getHandler().post(() -> {
            if (flippedBitmap != null) {
                GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
                GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
                GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, flippedBitmap, 0);

                VideoFrame.I420Buffer i420Buf = yuvConverter.convert(buffer);

                long frameTime = System.nanoTime() - start;
                VideoFrame videoFrame = new VideoFrame(i420Buf, 180, frameTime);
                capturerObserver.onFrameCaptured(videoFrame);
                videoFrame.release();
                try {
                    viewBitmap.recycle();
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
                handler.postDelayed(viewCapturer, VIEW_CAPTURER_FRAMERATE_MS);
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception ignored) {

    }
}

@Override
public void stopCapture() throws InterruptedException {
    this.checkNotDisposed();
    CustomVideoCapturer.this.surfaceTextureHelper.stopListening();
    CustomVideoCapturer.this.capturerObserver.onCapturerStopped();
    started.set(false);
    handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
    handlerPixelCopy.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
}

@Override
public void changeCaptureFormat(int width, int height, int framerate) {
    this.checkNotDisposed();
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    this.isDisposed = true;
}

@Override
public boolean isScreencast() {
    return true;
}

private void sendFrame() {
    final long captureTimeNs = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toNanos(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());

    /*surfaceTextureHelper.setTextureSize(width, height);

    int[] textures = new int[1];
    GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);

    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.preTranslate(0.5f, 0.5f);
    matrix.preScale(1f, -1f);
    matrix.preTranslate(-0.5f, -0.5f);


    YuvConverter yuvConverter = new YuvConverter();
    TextureBufferImpl buffer = new TextureBufferImpl(width, height,
            VideoFrame.TextureBuffer.Type.RGB, textures[0],  matrix,
            surfaceTextureHelper.getHandler(), yuvConverter, null);

    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
    GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, viewBitmap, 0);

    long frameTime = System.nanoTime() - captureTimeNs;
    VideoFrame videoFrame = new VideoFrame(buffer.toI420(), 0, frameTime);
    capturerObserver.onFrameCaptured(videoFrame);
    videoFrame.release();

    handler.postDelayed(viewCapturer, VIEW_CAPTURER_FRAMERATE_MS);*/

    // Create video frame
    JavaI420Buffer buffer = JavaI420Buffer.allocate(viewBitmap.getWidth(), viewBitmap.getHeight());
    bitmapToI420(viewBitmap, buffer);
    VideoFrame videoFrame = new VideoFrame(buffer,
            0, captureTimeNs);

    // Notify the listener
    if (started.get()) {
        ++this.numCapturedFrames;
        this.capturerObserver.onFrameCaptured(videoFrame);
    }
    if (started.get()) {
        handler.postDelayed(viewCapturer, VIEW_CAPTURER_FRAMERATE_MS);
    }
}

public long getNumCapturedFrames() {
    return this.numCapturedFrames;
}

/**
 * reduces the size of the image
 *
 * @param image
 * @param maxSize
 * @return
 */
public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap image, int maxSize) {
    int width = image.getWidth();
    int height = image.getHeight();

    try {
        Bitmap bitmap =  Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, width, height, true);
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, out);
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray()));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public void onFrame(VideoFrame videoFrame) {

}


}
```

Step 2 (Usage):

```
CustomVideoCapturer videoCapturer = new CustomVideoCapturer(arSceneView, 20);
videoSource = peerConnectionFactory.createVideoSource(videoCapturer.isScreencast());
videoCapturer.initialize(surfaceTextureHelper, context, videoSource.getCapturerObserver());
videoCapturer.startCapture(resolutionHeight, resolutionWidth, 30);
```

At after this you should be able to stream your AR frames to the remote user.

Step 3 (Optional):

You can play around with the `getResizedBitmap()` to change the resolution and size of your frames. REMEMBER: Operations with bitmaps can be process intensive.

I'm free to any type of suggestions or optimisations in this code. This is something I came up with after weeks of hustle.

Comment: Hi @Jaswant can you share your code. I am facing this issue. If you share it will helpful for me. My email - rranjithkumar100@gmail.com

Comment: Please check the edited part. You'll have a clarity.

Comment: Hi , i have done same thing , sharing the screen of my app and then sending using webrtc , want to understand your edited part how can i achieve that , actually i am also trying to achieve spomething like this (Dont want screensharing as dont want any sensitive data to be displayed apart from my arsession / arcamera)

Comment: Use PixelCopy to create bitmaps of your AR Session. And then feed those frames to a custom view capturer class as I mentioned. You have to create bitmaps rapidly like 20fps = 20 bitmaps/sec. 
 Now convert those bitmaps to WebRTC frames by converting them to YUV. Finally, pass those frames to the onFrameCaprured function inside your viewcapturer.

I created an AR Remote assistance platform using this.

Comment: Please check the Edited 2 Part

Comment: what is surfaceTexturehelper?

Comment: final EglBase.Context eglBaseContext = EglBase.create().getEglBaseContext();
SurfaceTextureHelper surfaceTextureHelper = SurfaceTextureHelper.create("CaptureThread", eglBaseContext);

Comment: for webrtc integration i suing this git code https://github.com/Jeffiano/ScreenShareRTC, Which one u used it will be great . Another thing is YUVConverter is not public in org.webrtc and last thing after giving SUrfaceHelper i was getting no implemetaion found for some nativeInitalized... in peerconnection

Comment: The implementation I shared required you to use the google webrtc. You are using libjingle which is a wrapper over webrtc. You need to find something similar to what I mentioned that should be compatible with libjingle. 
Although libjingle is good and easy to understand. my recommendation will be you should move to webrtc if you want maximum control over the library.

Comment: in google webrtc also YUVConvertor is not public how to use that , u hv any specific ,arr file or gradle please post i will try with that. And also any sample code i can get how to use google webrtc

Comment: I manually converted to YUV. please check the posted code. You cant find the YUV converter. its a custom function. Have a look into the code. bitmapToI420() function. 
I420 is YUV.

Comment: import org.webrtc.YuvConverter; in ur custom video capture i see this line in android studio i get that YuvConverter is not public and can not be access outside org.webrtc package.

Thanks a lot for your time and help . Really appreciate

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224990/discussion-between-aman-and-jaswant-singh).

Comment: Is Step 2 supposed to work? Why is there commented out code? With code commented I get no video, other wise I get E/Pixel_copy-->: Couldn't create bitmap of the SurfaceView error.

Comment: Yes. It needs to be commented out. The frames are being built from the handler call above the commented code. Also check your pixelcopy code for are frames being generated or not?

Comment: Uploaded to GitHub : https://github.com/jaswant-iotric/Android-ARCore-WebRTC-Video-Capturer